# Compile two golang files into one executable and run in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a go program with a main.go and a sub.go. When I run it under the debugger, main cannot see the function defined in sub. I tried creating a tasks.json but when I run it nothing happens.]

The MS documentaiton linked is for Node Package Manager and it doesn't state where the identifier for the task is placed in the configuration file

Here is my tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "go run crypto.go sbox.go state.go utility.go"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Never use go run with filename arguments. Don't use go run at all.

Comment: If I don't say "run" it won't run, right? What should be the correct command

Comment: It doesn't do any good to tell me that it doesn't work the way I am doing it. I already knew that

Comment: @AnnaNaden The key thing isn't that it doesn't work the way you're doing it, the key takeaway here is that you shouldn't even try to make it work. `go run` is something you shouldn't be using.

Comment: So please tell me what I should be using

Comment: I just want to debug a program that has two source files. That is supported by go language isnt it

Comment: Use `go build`.

Comment: I used go build and I can build an executable. How do I get the debugger to attach to it

Comment: Use go build from the command line or somehow trigger it as a task in tasks.json. Please provide some context, a few more words! Thanks

Comment: dlv exec or dlv attach.

Comment: Installing dlv appears to be completely impossible. If you feel that it is in fact possible, please back up your opinion with remarks longer than four words!